# Getting a junk value from copying a file using get()

Tags: c++, io

So I wrote some code that will copy a file by opening the file to be copied and then copying from it char by char using get. Code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "ERROR: Invalid number of arguments.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);
    ofstream outputFile(argv[2]);
    char c;
    if (inputFile.is_open() && outputFile.is_open()) {
        while (!(inputFile.eof())) {
            c = inputFile.get();
            outputFile << c;
        }
    }

    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file(s).\n";
        return 1;
    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

It copies the text over perfectly, except that there's always a junk character being read in. Why is this junk character being read in, and how do I prevent this? (Note: I know there are better ways to copy a file, but I have to do so using get()).

Answer (score 2):

The loop should go like this:

```
for (int c; (c = inputFile.get()) != EOF; )
{
    if (!outputFile.put(c))
    {
        // fatal: write error, die
    }
}
```

Comment: `int c` not `char c` or `EOF` may not be representable. All a bit sad really; K&R would not be impressed.

Comment: @AlanStokes: yes, of course, and I actually knew this. D'oh. Thanks :-)